# How should I use TransE for the knowledge graph embedding?

Tags: graph-embedding

I'm trying to get the node embeddings in the knowledge graph using TransE.
But there are some confusing concepts for node embedding using TransE.

I found the general TransE code, and it contained a dataset split for training and testing.
But when I need to get the embedding vectors for the overall nodes in the knowledge graph, should I not split them into training/test datasets?
How can I obtain the embedding vectors for 'all' nodes in the knowledge graph for the downstream tasks?