# How can I get knowledge graph embedding by using TransE?

Tags: data-preprocessing, embeddings

I saw nobody answered [Ssong](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601566/how-should-i-use-transe-for-the-knowledge-graph-embedding), however now I'm struggling with the same question. Can anyone help? Thanks.